# How to Parse Command Line Arguments in a Cmder Alias

Tags: cmder

I have created an alias to open an older git version of a file in sublime text.

My alias accepts 2 arguments, *$1* is the revision and *$2* is the file path,
but I would like to parse the arguments to get the file extension of the file to open it in its correct format.

My existing code is here:

```
revise=git show $1:$2 > redirected.txt $T C:/PROGRA~1/SUBLIM~2/sublime_text.exe redirected.txt
```

However I would like to to something like:

```
revise=git show $1:$2 > redirected.{$2.extesnion} $T   C:/PROGRA~1/SUBLIM~2/sublime_text.exe redirected.{$2.extesnion}
```

Comment: I don't really see any valid `bash` code here. Aliases (when correctly declared with the `alias` keyword) don't take arguments, and it isn't clear what `$T` is supposed to be.

Comment: that's a cmder alias that does accept aliases and the $T is the seperator

Comment: Those are for `cmd.exe` sessions, not `bash` sessions. The two are not compatible.

Answer (score 1):

environment details:

- cmder version: 1.3.15.1010

in cmd.exe session you can read parameters from the command line using the *$** placeholder to get everything that comes after the alias, alias example:

```
vi=vim $*
```

alias usage:

```
D:\
λ vi test.txt
```

Or you can read space-delimited argument using placeholders *$1, $2, $n...* alias example:

```
example= echo param one: $1    param two: $2
```

alias usage:

```
D:\
λ example hi how are you?
```

alias result:

```
param one: hi    param two: how
```

note *-are-* and *-you?-* where no echoed